# What is the maximum size of a comment property from Workspacecheckinparameters TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, maxlength

Comment property from [Workspacecheckinparameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspacecheckinparameters.comment(v=vs.110).aspx) class has maxlength limit ?

Usage: http://manyrootsofallevilrants.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/check-outcheck-in-code-programmatically.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in comment is stored in SQL Database. You can find it in Tfs_DefaultCollection →   dbo.tbl.ChangeSet →Comment(nvarchar(max),null).

So the maximum  size of a comment property should be the maximum characters for the **NVARCHAR(MAX).** According to MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx  max indicates that **the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB).** The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes.

[image]

Comment: Which the name of SQL Database?

Comment: It's the Data Tier of TFS, the one configured when you install TFS.